# Okta apps validation

Tags: authentication, okta

I have 3 okta apps setup.

1. Okta app for backend
2. Okta spa app
3. Okta web app

The Okta spa app is able to use the access token it got and pass to Okta app for backend and the token is validated. However, the Okta web app access token when passed to Okta app for backend, could not be validated, thus token is not valid.

Anyone know the proper setup for the Okta web app so where its access token can be validated against the Okta app for backend?

Comment: there are a lot of moving parts which can affect your environment. I'd start with grabbing access tokens and look at them with https://jwt.io to see if something obvious sticks out

Comment: I did try that. I have several Okta spa apps and all of them return the same KID from the JWT header. They all were validated successfully. However, the Oka web app has a different KID. But I'm not even sure how to make it where the Okta app for backend will validate the Okta web app successfully.

Comment: kid is not the issue here, I'd check `aud`, `iss` fields for both tokens